# Page wise total in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am using a data grid in my page, in which I am displaying a cost column. my page contains 1000s of records. i am displaying 25 records per page. And I have to display the total in the footer. and the problem is i want to display the total by page wise. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

[DataGrid.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx)

Add each values in the corresponding cell and display the total amount.

Same is done in this page.

[Use of DataGrid ItemDataBound Event (C#)](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives3/archive570.html)

Comment: I have displayed the total. I want to calculate it page by page. how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

On your gridview's RowDataBound event add your values to a page level variable,

```
void OrderGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        // add your value to a local variable here.
    }
}
```

and at the RowCreated event, check if the row is footer, and then add your total to your footer :

```
void OrderGridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) {

        // add your total to footer here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Canavar, 
I have did the same in my page. I want to calculate the total page by page.